# CPAN fails installing module Math::Pari (fetching GP/PARI)

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm on linux (debian buster) and currently trying to install the perl module 'Crypt::Random' which has a dependency to 'Math::Pari':

```
/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install Crypt::Random'
```

This fails when it get's to fetching GP/PARI:

```
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 13 Feb 2021 13:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Crypt::Random'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/V/VI/VIPUL/Crypt-Random-1.52.tar.gz ok
Configuring V/VI/VIPUL/Crypt-Random-1.52.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Math::Pari 2.001804 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Crypt::Random
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  VIPUL/Crypt-Random-1.52.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for V/VI/VIPUL/Crypt-Random-1.52.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----      VIPUL/Crypt-Random-1.52.tar.gz      ----
    Math::Pari [requires]
Running install for module 'Math::Pari'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.030518.zip ok
Configuring I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.030518.zip with Makefile.PL
Did not find GP/PARI build directory around.

Do you want to me to fetch GP/PARI automatically?

  (If you do not, you will need to fetch it manually, and/or direct me to
   the directory with GP/PARI source via the command-line option paridir=/dir)

Make sure you have a large scrollback buffer to see the messages, or `tee'
the STDOUT/STDERR to a file.

Fetch? (y/n, press Enter) y
Getting GP/PARI from ftp://megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/
Cannot create FTP object: Connection timed out at utils/Math/PariBuild.pm line 446.

Can't fetch file with Net::FTP, now trying with LWP::UserAgent...
Can't fetch directory listing from ftp://megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/: 500 Connection timed out
Client-Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 15:23:12 GMT    

...

Not in this directory, trying `http://megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/'...
Can't fetch directory listing from http://megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/: 500 Can't connect to megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr:80 (Connection timed out)
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 15:34:08 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to megrez.math.u-bordeaux.fr:80 (Connection timed out)

Connection timed out at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 50.

...
```

It takes quite some time (it's trying differnt paths through ftp and http / LWP) and then ends up in kind of an endless loop with this:

```
Not in this directory, trying `'...
Can't fetch directory listing from : 400 URL missing
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 15:43:50 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

400 URL missing
```

Canceling it with Ctrl+C lets the installation continue but it fails because of the missing module Mth::Pari.

I tried to connect to the domain with different tools (ftp http) and different networks (DSL and mobile), but it seems like the domain is not responding.

Does anyone have an idea, what's going on there?

Is there another way to get the missing modules installed, in case the domain is not accessible (I'm new to perl and CPAN and didn't find any hints while searching on the web yet)?

Thanks for your hints in advance!

Comment: Seems like the site https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/ is down. You can try download from [here](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/pari-2.13.1.tar.gz) instead

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks for the hint! Id did try that one (downloaded and installed), but on the installation of Crypt::Random it's not recognized (cpan still wants to fetch it). I guess, it's because of the different version. The one you pointed me to is newer that the dependency. But I'm actually not sure if I could / should point cpan to use that version. If so, how?

Comment: The site seems to be working again now. Running `cpan Math::Pari` works fine here now.

Comment: Just recognized that the server is responding again. The auto fetch is working again (it takes version 2.3.5 ("last golden version", what ever it means...).